# git command to show branch/feature name from a sha1 hash

Tags: linux, git, git-log

How do I get the branch/feature name from a sha1 hash on the command line?

Also how is this done using pretty=format syntax.

I see that it's done somehow using this method

```
git log --graph --full-history --all --color \  
--pretty=format:"%x1b[31m%h%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%s"
```

but I don't know which line is causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get the branch/feature name from a sha1 hash on the command line?

You can use...

```
git branch --contains <sha1>
```